# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Cell borders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

How do we conditional format (not the color, but) the borders of cell/s, in Google Sheets?

I couldn't find this option.

Comment: So far I know it is not possible by cf. May be need some appscript.

Comment: possible only with script